# Antónimo de insípido

Tags: adjetivos, antónimos

En una conversación en familia surgió esta duda sobre el antónimo de insípido.

Aunque en wordreference encontré una respuesta, no me convence del todo y en el sitio de la RAE encuentro la definición pero no hay referencia al antónimo por lo que hago la pregunta aquí.

¿Cuál es la palabra que mejor se acomoda a ser antónimo de **insípido**?

Comment: Entiendo que a lo mejor no quieres influenciar en las posibles respuestas diciendo cuál es el antónimo que encontraste, pero por otro lado si dijeses por qué no te convence, se podría dar lugar a una discusión más amplia (discutiendo otras posibilidades en principio no evidentes que satisfagan "los requisitos" donde el otro término no lo hace) o en mayor profundidad (acerca del término que no te convence).

Comment: Tal cuál @Diego Una búsqueda rápida en google me llevó a **sabroso** y supuse que seria la primera respuesta, tal como sucedió. No me convence del todo porque **insípido** es sin sabor alguno mientras que sabroso no solo es que tiene sabor sino un **buen sabor**. Algo de mal sabor no lo llamaríamos insípido pero eso no lo haría sabroso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Sápido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XGyqwkB) es un sinónimo de sabroso, pero tiene la connotación de que algo tiene "algún sabor" mientras que "sabroso" llega a ser "**Delicioso**, gustoso, deleitable al ánimo".

Si buscamos algo "superlativo" para el rato de sabor podemos usar entonces "[exquisito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HLo5xx8)" para señalar que algo es (en sabor)

> De singular y extraordinaria calidad, primor o gusto en su especie.

"[Suculento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ycvgqfx)" sería otro adjetivo que podemos usar para evidenciar que algo tiene sabor y calidad y es apetecible al gusto.

> Jugoso, sustancioso, exquisito

En cualquier caso, la mayoría de esos sinónimos hacen referencia a "buen sabor" cuando un antónimo de "insípido" sería que algo tiene en cierta medida sabor, ya sea agradable o desagradable. Por eso yo me quedaría con "**sápido**" como antónimo de "insípido".

Comment: Qué gran descubrimiento la palabra _sápido_

Comment: "Sápido" es un gran descubrimiento, pero la consideraría antónima de insípido solamente en su primera acepción: "falto de sabor". En su segunda acepción ("que no tiene el grado de sabor que debiera o pudiera tener") se entiende que algo de sabor ya hay, pero no llega a tener el nivel que debería. En este caso sí consideraría a "sabroso" como el antónimo correcto.

Comment: Esto era lo que estaba buscando. Que pena disentir de la mayoría que ha votado mayoritariamente la respuesta de fedorqui pero esta es la respuesta que buscaba. Gracias tocayo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo  Sabroso no me convence del todo porque insípido es sin sabor alguno mientras que sabroso no solo es que tiene sabor sino **un buen sabor**. Algo de mal sabor no lo llamaríamos insípido pero eso no lo haría sabroso. Por el contrario la definición de **sápido** es sencillamente que tiene **algún** sabor sin distinguir si es bueno o no.

Comment: @DGaleano entiendo y apruebo tu razonamiento, pero entiendo también que entonces buscabas el antónimo de "insípido" en su primera acepción. Lo digo porque también se puede usar cuando esperas que algo tenga un sabor determinado (que generalmente es un sabor bueno, por ejemplo cuando degustas un potaje) y no se ha llegado al punto de sabor que te gusta. Ahí también puedes decir que el plato está insípido (en el sentido de "soso"), pero eso no quiere decir que esté completamente falto de sabor, sino que no ha llegado a estar como te gusta. Ahí el antónimo sería otro.

Answer (score 8):

Teniendo en cuenta que la RAE define [*insípido*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ll5gYt7) como *Falto de sabor* o *Que no tiene el grado de sabor que debiera o pudiera tener*, en el plano estrictamente gastronómico yo apostaría por centrarme en la parte de la falta de sabor y buscar aquello que específicamente lo tiene:

> [**sabroso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WuWsJ0U)
>   Del lat. saporōsus.
>   1. adj. Sazonado y grato al sentido del gusto.
>   2. adj. Delicioso, gustoso, deleitable al ánimo.

Comment: Esa fue la definición que encontré en wordreference que no me convenció del todo ya que sabroso es que sabe bueno y no simplemente que tiene algún sabor. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Nunca puede ser sabroso. Por ejemplo, si algo es "inodoro, incoloro e insípido", lo contrario es colorido, de sápido amargor y emanando un odorífero pestilente. Colorido es alegre, por lo tanto sería coloro (pero coloro feo? colorado? colorete?

Answer (score 0):

El problema con *sápido* es que poca gente conoce el término.  Así que ofrezco otra opción:

**sazonado**

> *[sazonar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XNDIW6s)*: Dar sazón a la comida.
>
> *[sazón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XNAUzjg)*: Gusto y sabor que se percibe en los alimentos.

El plato no tiene que estar *bien* sazonado; no tiene que tener buen o mal sabor.  Pero algunos ingredientes se han agregado para darle algún sabor.
Entonces si algo está *sazonado*, no será *insípido*, que es *falto de sabor*.